# Acceleration in direction of motion dependent on reference frame?

Tags: linear-transformations

I’ve been programming a rocket flight simulation and I apply short bursts of thrust when required. I noticed however that the rocket would take wildly different paths depending on the reference frame. Intuitively it doesn’t make sense since a rocket’s thrust shouldn’t depend on a mathematical construct. The deciding factor here is that the thrust is happening in the direction of the velocity which is not independent of the reference frame. I’m using following formula to apply an instantaneous $\Delta v$ to the rocket:

$$v’=v+\frac{v}{|v|}\Delta v$$

Based on the formula the dependence is clear but I still can’t intuitively reason why my rocket’s boost should be dependent on the reference frame.

If anyone can produce any insights on the formula and why it’s probably wrong it would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: As you write yourself, the velocity is *not* independent of the reference frame. Therefore the boost, the acceleration, will also not be it although it should be. Don't you want the boost to be in the direction of the rocket instead of in the direction of the velocity?

Comment: Positions and their higher derivatives (velocities, accelerations) are vector quantities. In a formula like vec(v)= vec(v at t=0)+ vec(accel)*Delta(t), supposing that accel does not depend on time, all quantities are vectors and must be added according to vector algebra. So things are not depending on the reference frame [i.e. that sum is independent of any reference frame] but as soon as the values are specified in a reference frame, everything is.

Comment: I expect the rocket to be aligned towards the direction of motion so the rocket's direction would be the same right? It could be that that doesn't make sense but that seems to be the case with most vehicles.